# HTML Formatted String inserting into TextViews and EditText

Tags: android, html, formatting, textview, android-edittext

I have a database that will store an HTML tagged text to retain formatting information from an EditText. I create this string using HTML.toHtml(EditText.getText). I notice this method wraps whatever Spanned Text is put in it with `<p> and </p>`. The issue with that is when I got to use the method HTML.fromHtml(HTMLFormattedString) and then use the setText method of either a TextView or EditText there are two extra lines at the end of my actual text, which makes sense because that is how the paragraph tag works with HTML.

Is there any way to make the textView or EditText shrink to not display the extra blank lines? What is the simplest way to do this? I have experimented with just removing the last `<p> and </p>`, but that only works if the user did not enter 3 or more new lines with the return key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up searching for white space at the end of the spanned text that was created and removed it. This took care of extra spaces due to the `<p> </p>` and was less time consuming than overriding the mentioned class to achieve the same results.

```
public SpannableStringBuilder trimTrailingWhitespace(
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableString) {

    if (spannableString == null)
        return new SpannableStringBuilder("");

    int i = spannableString.length();

    // loop back to the first non-whitespace character
    while (--i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(spannableString.charAt(i))) {
    }

    return new SpannableStringBuilder(spannableString.subSequence(0, i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is just a round about approach. I had the same issue. And you are provided with two options,

1)As you said that paragraph tag works the way what you have suspected. What it does , it appends two "\n" values to the end of each <\p> tag. So you can convert the html to string and remove the last two characters which are usually two "\n"s

or

2) You have get into the Html Class itself. That is, you have to override the HTML class and look for `handleP(SpannableStringBuilder text)` and change its core logic a little bit.

```
private static void handleP(SpannableStringBuilder text) {
    int len = text.length();

    if (len >= 1 && text.charAt(len - 1) == '\n') {
        if (len >= 2 && text.charAt(len - 2) == '\n') {
            return;
        }
        text.append("\n");
        return;
    }

    if (len != 0) {
        text.append("\n\n");


    }
}
```

As you can see here, it appends two "\n" in `len!=0` which is were you have to do the change.

Comment: +1 for thinking about going to the docs. Where exactly do you look btw? Just being lazy to look it up myself.

Comment: Vinay you find it here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter.handleP%28android.text.SpannableStringBuilder%29

Comment: The problem here is that the class that you are referring to is protected and you cannot override the method. Essentially at that point you are recreating a custom HTML Class.

Comment: yes. That's what I meant.. Its tricky. You have to override the support classes with a tagsoup jar added to your project. But that's how I did it.

Comment: Would you post parts of what you did.